# spawn ETXTBSY error while launching chromimum using puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth using lambda function

Tags: web-scraping, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to scrape a webpage. Somehow it works locally, but when I upload the code as a lambda function it gives this error
[image]

My Code:

```
let browser = null;
  try {
    puppeteerExtra.use(StealthPlugin());
    browser = await puppeteerExtra.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
      headless: "new",
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
      width: 1620,
      height: 900,
    });
    await page.goto(NEWS_PAGE_URL, {
      timeout: 18900000,
    });

    console.log("open");

    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const acceptButton = document.querySelector(".accept-all");
      acceptButton.click();
    });
    console.log("open");
    const pages = await browser.pages();

    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
    console.log("open");
    let originalOffset = 0;
    while (true) {
      await page.evaluate("window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
      await page.waitForTimeout(500);
      let newOffset = await page.evaluate("window.pageYOffset");
      if (originalOffset === newOffset) {
        break;
      }
      originalOffset = newOffset;
    }
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
    console.log("open");
    const pageContent = await page.content();
    // console.log(pageContent);
    await pages[0].close();
    await pages[1].close();

    await browser.close();
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "parser",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sparticuz/chromium": "^116.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1441.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "puppeteer": "^21.1.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "^21.1.0",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2"
  }
}
```

I have used other solution using chrome-aws-lambda, but it did not work. This error is always showing.What is the problem? can anyone help?

Comment: Same here. I've been chasing this for over 30 hours. I'm importing @sparticuz/chromium v116.0.0 and puppeteer-core v21.1.0 installing into layer with nodejs/node_modules. Could it be architecture related? Lambda output:

2023-08-28T15:17:28.104Z
INFO executablePath: /tmp/chromium
ERROR Error: spawn ETXTBSY
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
    at new Process  {
  errno: -26,
  code: 'ETXTBSY',
  syscall: 'spawn'

Comment: I think too it is related to aws lambda architecture. I have moved to AWS ECS service instead of lambda